# Error of Graph disconnected is raised when I create an autoencoder

Tags: python, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am trying to create an autoencoder, but I meet this error `raise ValueError( ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 32), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'") at layer "dense_2". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []`

I need to use the way to `AE.add_loss(recon_loss)` to add the loss function of my autoencoder. Here is the code I used to build that autoecoder:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda, Reshape, Dense, Input, Activation
from keras.losses import mse
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam


ini = 'glorot_uniform'


""" build autoencoder model"""
# encoder
X = Input(shape=(64,))

# output of encoder or transmitted vector

# encoder
enc_1 = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=ini)(X)
enc_2 = Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=ini)(enc_1)

U = Lambda(lambda x: np.sqrt(32) * K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(enc_2)


# decoder
X_en = Input(shape=(32,))
dec_1 = Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=ini)(X_en)
dec_2 = Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=ini)(dec_1)
dec_3 = Dense(64, activation='linear', kernel_initializer=ini)(dec_2)
X_hat = dec_3

# model enc and dec
encoder = Model(X, U)
decoder = Model(X_en, X_hat)

# Define the autoencoder model
autoencoder_input = X
autoencoder_output = decoder(U)
AE = Model(autoencoder_input, autoencoder_output)

"""Training"""
# loss design
recon_loss = mse(X, X_hat)

### training ###
AE.add_loss(recon_loss)
AE.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001))
```